# How do I implement just a hamburger icon with no toolbar?

Tags: java, android, navigation, icons, drawer

I have a `DashboardActivity` class that has a `ViewPager` and labels above the `ViewpPager` to indicate the current tab that the user is in. I have implemented a navigation drawer in my app. I did not use fragments, just used `DashboardActivity extends NavDrawer` so I get the layout there. My results are as follows [Nav Drawer on DashboardActivity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVimU.png). However, I would like to have my hamburger icon on the left of the `Home` tab in the UI on a layout like this [Desired output (but missing nav drawer icon)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6FlR.png) 
.How can remove the toolbar and make the Navigation Drawer icon appear to the left of my tabs ("Home, SOS, Notifications").

My activity_dashboard XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_sans_semibold"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textColor="@color/textTabBright"
        android:textSize="22sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblSOS"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_sans_semibold"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="SOS"
        android:textColor="@color/textTabLight"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblNotifications"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fontFamily="@font/nunito_sans_semibold"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="Notifications"
        android:textColor="@color/textTabLight"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/tabs_layout"
    android:id="@+id/main_Pager">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

My `NavDrawer` class `setContentView()`

```
  @Override
public void setContentView(final int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(R.layout.nav_drawer);
    android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_Layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID,(ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.fragment_container));
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `Toolbar`, `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. Add an `ImageView` or `ImageButton` where you want with your desired hamburger icon. Open the `DrawerLayout` when you click on your new hamburger.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you